# onetoone database relation between two tables?

Tags: python, sql, django, database

**I have 4 tables already exist in system.**

1. Account
2. Project
3. document
4. Catalog

There are many Accounts in the system and each Account many have many Projects, each project have many documents.
[Current system not handle same project name in a different Accounts]

**catalog Table**:

```
class catalog(models.Model):
    catalog_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    documents = models.ManyToManyField(document, blank=True, null=True)
```

Current system map documents of any project in the Catalog table.
We create `catalog_name` by `project_name` and add documents in the `document`
So Project name can not be repeated.

**Project Table**:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    FK_Account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True)
    Project_ID = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    Project_Name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

**document Table**:

```
class document(models.Model):
    uid = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,db_index=True)
```

**Code to get Project documents**:

```
def getAllProjectDocument(self, project_obj, current_selected_option='All'):
    """ Returns All Project Documents.        """
    docs = []
    cat_obj_list = catalog.objects.filter(catalog_name = project_obj.Project_Name + "-user-catalog")
    if cat_obj_list:
        catobj = cat_obj_list[0]
        if current_selected_option=="All":
            docs = catobj.documents.filter(status=2)
        else:
            docs = catobj.documents.filter(status=2, publish_status=int(current_selected_option))

    return docs
```

**Note**: status 2 means document is any on project.

There are `950000` documents and `300000` projects in the system. If I have to get `project documents` of the of all project then I have to query on the `catalog` table for each project i.e. `300000` time and again do `filtering` in according to `search` and then add query set objects to python list and pass to template after finishing `for` loop

So `for` loop is running for `300000` times then query on `catalog` for same count i.e. `300000` and filter again same count i.e. ``300000` . So apache memory is increases.

**I come with following idea : This is migration of Database.**

I am going to create table which have one to one mapping og project and document.
There are are 4 types of document- 1. Private, 2. Project, 3. Library, 4. Delete document.

```
class Project_Document(models.Model):
    FK_Project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True)
    FK_Dcoument = models.ForeignKey(document, blank=True, null=True)
```

**So is **`onetoone`** mapping is correct or anyone have different way to do this?**

Comment: I don't understand your current structure. What is the relationship between catalog and project?

Comment: There is no `ontoone` or `manytomany` relation,  Added function to `getAllProjectDocument` . just created row in a Catalog table with project name and assign document to manytomany files

Answer (score 1):

Your ProjectDocument table is really just a many-to-many relationship, exactly as you already have between Catalog and Document. I don't think adding another one would really help, especially as you would then have to ensure the two relationships are kept in sync.

Instead you should add the missing relationship directly between Catalog and Project; I can't tell from the code whether that should be a one-to-many (ForeignKey) or one-to-one, and if the former which direction it should go. But assuming each Project has multiple Catalogs, you would add a ForeignKey on Catalog pointing at Project; then you could get all the Documents for a Project with one query:

```
project_docs = Document.objects.filter(catalog__project=my_project)
```

Note also you have some big inefficiencies in your table; you seem to be using TextFields throughout, which are stored as blobs in the database, and therefore have a massive overhead. You should be using CharFields for things like IDs and names; TextFields are only for large blocks of text such as the body content of a document itself.

Comment: I can not do in catalog table because catalog table is used for account, user, library document mapping. I will create new table of Document and Project mapping. So which is better onetoone or manytomany because I need to handle add and remove event of documents in a project.